# Turning off SRTP in firefox

Tags: webrtc, rtsp, rtp

Can we disable SRTP from firefox, a possible equivalent for `--disable-webrtc-encryption` provided for [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624382/can-i-turn-off-srtp-when-use-webrtc).